# Node is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: node.js

> C:\Users\Luke\Documents\NodeGettingStarted>node program.js
>   'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I have file called program in `NodeGettingStarted` folder.

But I have run into this issue straight away, I see people and those in my course not having issue. They can type node `program.js` and node will put words from file into node.

Comment: did you install nodejs? https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Answer (score 0):

You must install node.js in your Operative System 
[Download](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)